# Mobile only empty space between equal css-float div

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-float

I have the following HTML/CSS: https://codepen.io/neilnm/pen/MqYONR

```
.container2{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(40,149,68,0.9);
    color: white;
    font-size: 55px;
}
```

In browsers it looks fine but on mobile devices (especially iPhone6S Plus) I get this empty space between the two floating div:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the space between the elements based on the screen resolution, you need to make use of media queries. Common screen resolutions can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and additional information on media queries and how to use them can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/#apply_media_queries_based_on_viewport_size).